# NoReverseMatch at /blog Reverse for 'single_blog' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['single_blog/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I tried many times but the page not rendering , i am not understanding where i did wrong? could you please let me know , where i did wrong?

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
head = models.CharField(blank=False, unique=True, max_length=250)
date_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
description = models.TextField(blank=False, max_length=1000)
by_name = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, unique=True, max_length=250)
by_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.head
```

views.py

```
def blog(request):
blogs = Post.objects.all()
return render(request, 'blog.html', {'blogs': blogs})

def blog(request):
blogs = Post.objects.all()
return render(request, 'blog.html', {'blogs': blogs})
```

def dynamicblog(request, id):
obj = Post.objects.get(id=id)
return render(request, 'single_blog.html', {'obj': obj})

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.home, name='home'),
path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
path('shop', views.shop, name='shop'),
path('service', views.service, name='service'),
path('blog', views.blog, name='blog'),
path('single_blog/<int:id>/', views.dynamicblog, name='single_blog'),
path('single_service', views.single_service, name='single_service'),
```

blog.html

```
{% for blog in blogs %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 news-block">
                <div class="news-block-two news-block-three wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                    <div class="inner-box">
                        <div class="image-holder">
                                <figure class="image-box"><img src="{{blog.by_img.url}}" alt=""></figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="lower-content">
                            <h4><a href="{% url 'single_blog' %}">{{blog.head}}</a></h4>
                            <div class="post-info">by {{blog.by_name}} on {{blog.date_time}}</div>
                            <div class="text">{{blog.description}}</div>
                            <div class="link-btn"><a href="{% url 'single_blog/{{blog.id}}' %}">Read More<i class="flaticon-slim-right"></i></a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

single_blog.html

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 sidebar-side">
                {% for blog in obj %}
                <div class="sidebar blog-sidebar">
                    <div class="contact-widget sidebar-widget wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="00ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
                        <div class="widget-content">
                            <h4>{{blog.head}}</h4>
                            <div class="text">Our industrial plant services keep your generator up</div>
                            <div class="btn-box"><a href="{% url 'contact' %}"><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>Contact Agent</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `single_blog` path expect some arguments. So pass it :

*blog.html*

```
{% for blog in blogs %}

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 news-block">
  <div class="news-block-two news-block-three wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="300ms" data-wow-duration="1500ms">
    <div class="inner-box">
      <div class="image-holder">
        <figure class="image-box"><img src="{{blog.by_img.url}}" alt=""></figure>
      </div>
      <div class="lower-content">
        <!--                              |  Here            -->
        <!--                              v                  -->
        <h4><a href="{% url 'single_blog' id=blog.id %}">{{blog.head}}</a></h4>
        <div class="post-info">by {{blog.by_name}} on {{blog.date_time}}</div>
        <div class="text">{{blog.description}}</div>
        <div class="link-btn">
          <!--                              |  Here            -->
          <!--                              v                  -->
          <a href="{% url 'single_blog' id=blog.id %}">Read More<i class="flaticon-slim-right"></i>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url)